# p5.js array of images and data retrieve with splice

Tags: arrays, image, p5.js, array-splice

I have an array of images and I want to use splice to retrieve an image from it.
But when I store the data and use it as the image argument in the image() function, I get an error:

`image()` was expecting `p5.Image|p5.Element__ for parameter #0 (zero-based index), received array instead

```js
    let arr;
    let retrieve;

    function preload() {

         water = loadImage('Images/water.png');
         ore = loadImage('Images/ore.png');
 }

          function setup() {

          createCanvas(1800, 1500);
          arr = [water, ore];

          retrieve = arr.splice(0, 1);
}

         function draw() {

         background(0);
         image(retrieve, 100, 100);
}
```

So I'm kind of confused because it seems to me that the variable `arr`should hold an image --- even if this image was part of an array before.
If I make an array of numbers or text, everything seems to work just fine.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs of [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

The function returns an array (even if no elements are removed):

> **Return value**
>
> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
> removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
> removed, an empty array is returned.

In your case to access the removed element itself you could use

```
retrieve = arr.splice(0, 1)[0];
```